# I just learned Java, what does count() mean in this code? Can anyone answer that？

Tags: java

I just learned Java, what does count() mean in this code? Can anyone answer that？
The following code:

```
try{
            int a[]=new int[4];
            count("udahfiu732687   734%&^%^",a);
            File file=new File("out.dat");
            FileWriter fileWriter=new FileWriter(file.getName());
            for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
                fileWriter.write(String.valueOf(a[i]+" "));
            fileWriter.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: Check the count function in your code

Comment: It’s a method call (in Java they are called methods; when some people here say *function*, they mean *method*). So there should be a `count` method somewhere in your class. Or possibly a static `count` method is imported into your source file.

Answer (score 1):

When the program reaches this statement

```
count("udahfiu732687   734%&^%^", a);
```

then it executes a java method named `count` and passes to arguments, a string and the reference to an empty array of integers with a length of 4.

I assume that the `count` method puts some numbers into the array.